# Is there a way to shorten this tkinter code by putting it in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want the first variable to be equivalent to the first item on the list, then the second to equals the second item and the third to equals the third. I've been trying to make this a loop but it doesn't work. I tried to use for i in range and indexing but it says event object does not support indexing. Is there any other way I could make this into a loop?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import random

WordsEasy1 = ["book","dictionary","paper","suitcase","jacket","box","folder","cabinet","abacus",
"access","monitor","mouse","pencil","light","button","keyboard","country","pet","dog","love",
"food","car","envelope","adapter","charger","board","tablet","cable","switch","case","rainbow",
"stick","spoon","develop","hat","hands","cup","coffee","tea","letters","vase","duck","ear","fan",
"clothes","shorts","pen","paint","alphabet","sound","money","basement","page","pause","break","fix",
"flag","feather","speaker","message","capital","airport","tango","drink","language","type","journalist",
"programmer","mountain","sunset","snow","ball","jersey","skirt","moon","remote","control","manual",
"take","sign","traffic","crown","grass","garden","wallpaper","explanation","idea","pants","gym","teach",
"bowl","shallow","deep","focus","strong","signal","process","screw","tools","quality","perseverance",
"beauty","change","darkness","eclipse","set","bee","train","microscope","crash","interrupt","vocal",
"can","failure","success","rate","graph","course","good","overlap","technique","yesterday","clock",
"speed","jar","frame","fast","duty","post","mail","laundry","gift","presentation","public","media",
"story","enhance","liberty","freedom","ownership","metal","cloud","virtual","reality","inception",
"natural","nature","television","share","meteor","master","depart","shrimp"]


wordeasy3a=[]
wordeasy3b=[]
wordeasy3c=[]


a=0
score=0
wrong=0

while a<3:
    we1=randint(0,150)
    wordeasyrw1=WordsEasy1[we1]
    if wordeasyrw1 not in wordeasy3a:
        wordeasy3a.append(wordeasyrw1)
        a+=1
    else:
        pass
if a==3:
    a=0

for i in wordeasy3a:
    print(i)


while a<3:
    we2=randint(0,150)
    wordeasyrw2=WordsEasy1[we2]
    if wordeasyrw2 not in wordeasy3a:
        wordeasy3b.append(wordeasyrw2)
        a+=1
    else:
        pass
if a==3:
    a=0

i=0

print()
for i in wordeasy3b:
    print(i)

root = Tk()

def answer1(event1):
    global score
    global wrong
    if event1.widget.get() == wordeasy3a[0]:
        score+=1
    else:
        wrong+=1
    print()
    print(score)
    print(wrong)

def answer2(event2):
    global score
    global wrong
    if event2.widget.get() == wordeasy3a[1]:
        score+=1
    else:
        wrong+=1
    print()
    print(score)
    print(wrong)

def answer3(event3):
    global score
    global wrong
    if event3.widget.get() == wordeasy3a[2]:
        score+=1
    else:
        wrong+=1
    print()
    print(score)
    print(wrong)


def userinput():
    E3 = Entry(root, bd =2)
    E3.pack ( side = BOTTOM)
    E3.bind('<Return>', answer3)

    E2 = Entry(root, bd =2)
    E2.pack ( side = BOTTOM)
    E2.bind('<Return>', answer2)

    E1 = Entry(root, bd =2)
    E1.pack ( side = BOTTOM)
    E1.bind('<Return>', answer1)


userinput()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just provide a sample function for all of them, and combine it with `lambda`? I don't really see how a loop would fit in the first scenario.

```
def answer(event, index):
    global score
    global wrong
    if event.widget.get() == list[index]:
        score+=1
    else:
        wrong+=1

def userinput():
    E1 = tk.Entry(root, bd=2)
    E1.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    E1.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(0): answer(event, arg))

    E2 = tk.Entry(root, bd=2)
    E2.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    E2.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(1): answer(event, arg))

    E3 = tk.Entry(root, bd=2)
    E3.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    E3.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(2): answer(event, arg))
```

I guess you could minimize the last bit into a loop, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it's best if your widgets have pointers.

```
def userinput():
    for i in range(3):
        temp = tk.Entry(root, bd=2)
        temp.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        temp.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(i): answer(event, arg))
```

Comment: I'm going to edit the code with what I actually have. I haven't used lambda before. How does it work?

Comment: Can you give the full error from the compiler? Like, the entire last line.

Comment: File "C:\Users\mdefoti\Desktop\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1456, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<module1>", line 87, in <lambda>
  File "<module1>", line 70, in answer
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Don't call your list "list" as that is already a function in Python. Try renaming it.

Comment: Updated last function. It works completely for me now.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. My code is identical to yours in the OP, save for the replaced `userinput()` and `answer(event, index)` functions directly from my post. Is it giving the same error?

Comment: Glad I could help!